# Select Code Doesn't Affect The Web Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a web form to save transactions in database and a button to display the previous action but it doesn't work although there is no error message.

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim nmb As Long = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) - 1
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dataConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sql1 As New SqlCommand("select * from internal_trans where numbr = @numbr", conn)
    sql1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numbr", nmb)

    conn.Open()
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adapter.SelectCommand = sql1
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
    Me.TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString

    adapter.Dispose()
    sql1.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?  Have you tried running the SQL command in SSMS?

Comment: thank you tim and yes i did through the debugger and the textbox1 and two change but not in the page

Comment: Are `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` dynamic controls?

Comment: Can you share your front-end code? Are you using any `UpdatePanels`? Is the button causing a postback?

Comment: thank you zgood - yes i'm using updatepanel and the button causing a postback think so

Comment: tim what do you mean with dynamic control ? i'm filling in them and doing insertion just fine and also select max numbr from table and fill textbox1 with new numbr on page load ok

Comment: Please share the related code in the aspx file, including the update panel.

Comment: thanks everyone i solved the problem , i just took the button out the updatepanel